# How to install the VLC module in Python

Tags: python, pip, vlc

I was trying to install VLC using PIP, but get the following error:

```
pip install VLC

Downloading/unpacking vlc
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement vlc
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for vlc
Storing complete log in C:\Users\rakeshb4\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: have you tried installing this one   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-vlc

Comment: Can you install any packages at all that way? This looks like a networking problem.

Comment: Did you try `pip search vlc` ? It has some useful hints about the VLC module (in particular that it's for a Mac), perhaps there's some other modules you can use.

Comment: I need a conda package for VLC.  Does anyone have one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The packages `vlc` seems to have currently issues on pypi. However, you are on Windows and this package appears to be for MacOS only (based on description).

Try `python-vlc` instead.

Answer (score 6):

I could solve the problem with :

```bash
pip install python-vlc
```

Answer (score 1):

solved with `pip install python-vlc`

Answer (score 0):

I could install this with: `pip install python-vlc`

Here is the link: https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/