# Getting audio from a URL and playing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, streaming

There is a link to an `mp3` file that needs to be streamed from a `URL` like `http://example.com/music_radio.mp3` and played on a computer. On the Internet, although there are examples of streaming audio, but they are mainly for `Python2`, and for `Python3` there are no such libraries anymore, I tried to do it this way:

```
import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer ("http://example.com/music_radio.mp3")
p.play ()
```

But it constantly displays an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "PythonProjects / URL /
>   main.py", line 2, in import vlc File "PythonProjects / URL / venv /
>   lib / python3.6 / site-packages / vlc / init.py", line 3, in public
>   import ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'public'

And the problem is that the `public` module is not installed. How can you solve this problem or how else can you receive and play audio by reference?

UPD: That link suggests either non-working code, or code using Python2, not Python3

UPD2: When using `python-vlc`, this error occurs:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "PythonProjects/URL/main.py", line 4, in 
>       import vlc   File "PythonProjects/URL/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vlc.py",
>   line 203, in 
>       dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()   File "PythonProjects/URL/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vlc.py",
>   line 194, in find_lib
>       ctypes.CDLL('libvlccore.dylib')   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ctypes/**init**.py",
>   line 348, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: dlopen(libvlccore.dylib, 6): image not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play mp3 from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171169/how-to-play-mp3-from-url)

Comment: @MatthewSmith, This link does not contain a solution to my question.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348607/how-to-install-the-vlc-module-in-python

Comment: @MatthewSmith Anyway error, but when using `python-vlc`

Answer (score 2):

If this can help

```
from IPython.display import Audio
Audio(url="http://www.nch.com.au/acm/8k16bitpcm.wav")
```