# Why do i get this error: "OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found"?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a YouTube VLC player but I run into this error: `OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`

Here is my code:

```
import vlc, pafy
url = ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihxYcQJuCrQ")
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
media = vlc.MediaPlayer(best.url)
media.play()
```

Is there a way to fix this or even an alternative for this?

Comment: Can you share the list of packages of the Conda environment? Are you using the base/root environment?

Comment: Try pip install vlc,pafy

Comment: This is the error i get if i pip install vlc

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vlc (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vlc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so trivial to debug.

Could you post the complete shell output, so we can see on which module it fails?

More info on what packages you have installed is useful.

- If you installed it via pip3 run `pip3 list` (or if you are still using python2 `pip list`)
- If you installed anaconda, could you provide the version?.

EDIT

Can list the packages you have installed in your project directory (or the virtual environment)?
Go to the directory where you saved the .py file and execute `conda list`.

If it is not the latest version you could try to upgrade.

Also VLC is installed, right?

EDIT2:

You could try creating a virtual environment for your project. This is generally the preferred way. It can help you to provide a stable environment for used packages on a project per project basis.

I found a [guide](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) on how to set it up with anaconda.

The virtual environment works by setting up a local site-packages in the project directory. This is separate from `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages`. Even if you have duplicate packages (they could have different versions) it should always take them from the virtual environment.

One thing to keep in mind is to always activate the environment when running the python script.

Comment: it seems when i do ```conda list``` VLC won't show?

Comment: If you do the `conda list` does is show python-vlc (or similar)?

With the comment "Also VLC is installed, right?" I was referring to the program VLC from videolan. The [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/) for python-vlc specifically mentions: "Note that it relies on an already present install of VLC."

Comment: nope does not show anything to do with python-vlc or VLC

Answer (score 2):

There is no `VLC` module (It's for MacOS), you should install `python-vlc`
Look more here: [How to install the VLC module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348607/how-to-install-the-vlc-module-in-python)

Comment: this is what i get when i do pip install python-vlc

Requirement already satisfied: python-vlc in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.0.11115)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Comment: So now you need to `import python-vlc` not `import VLC`